# What is the piece of code that only the developer of the bot can use?

Tags: c#, discord

I am not sure how to make the bot only give out the currency if I told it too and not other admins on the discord server.

```
[Command("give"), Alias("Give", "gift", "Gift"), Summary("Used to give or gift people golden coins")]
public async Task Give(IUser User = null, int Amount = 0)
{
    SocketGuildUser User1 = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
    if (!User1.GuildPermissions.Administrator)
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($":x: You don't have administrator permissions In this discord server! Ask a moderator or the owner to execute this command!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you get some error like '*not all code paths return a value*' with this code?

Comment: nope the bot works perfectly fine it's just that: "!User1.GuildPermissions.Administrator"

is the issue. I am not sure how to turn the permissions around that the bot will only respond to my account ID instead of admin permissions.

Comment: Don't cast with `as` if you don't do not-null checking right away. Your code is fine as long as you can guarantee that other people are not  `.Administrator`. Otherwise, your code is obviously wrong. You suppose to do additional checking there, like: `IsAdmin() && IsMe()`, where the last one checks something **uniquely** yours.

Comment: How would you write this code but only that you could access this command using only you account ID? Many Thanks.

Comment: The most stupid yet simple decision is to hardcode your ID. Pray it never changes. If you'd like more reliable approach, you have to redisign your solution. It might take a lot of efforts. `IsAdmin() && user.ID == 0`. Code might look a bit better if you will provide extension method: `.Administrator.IsKingOfKings()`.

Comment: @Rafalon Why would they get that error when it's an `async Task` method with an `await`?

Comment: May sound like it but the account ID is permanent well unless I lost my account somehow. Anyways if that would happen I would backup the database and take down the bot then change the hard coded ID and upload the new bot back up with the database.

Comment: @xFaffy go ahead and hardcode ID then. May the force be with you, young jedi.

Comment: Thank You, but how to do it? I mean change the `!User1.GuildPermissions.Administrator` to hardcode ID?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto well I'd have to read something on Tasks, because for me, the prototype `public [async] [type] [NameOfMethod]([params])` implies that `NameOfMethod` should `return` something of type `type`, unless `type` is `void`. But obviously `Task` is different, my bad

Comment: @xFaffy just extend the content of your single `if` statement: `if (...Admin && user.ID == 0)`.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov shouldn't it be `if(User1.ID != [hardcodedId])`?

Comment: @Rafalon won't change anything, since that guy is an adming anyway.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov Are `== 0` and `!= 0` the same thing to you?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov `!User1.GuildPermissions.Administrator && User.Id ==  myID)`

That will work?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov I want to remove the Admin permission tho and just hardcode this one command under my own unique ID.

Comment: @xFaffy `if (user.ID != [myId]) { PrintErrorMessageAndBlowUpEarth(); }`

Comment: @Rafalon oh you're right, I wan't attentive enough.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov gives me an error " Invalid Expression Term '[' "

Comment: @xFaffy replace `[myId]` with your ID.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov 

`SocketGuildUser User1 = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
 if (User.Id != [3XXXXXXXXXXXXX])
                {
                    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($":x: This is a developers command!");
                    return;
                }`

still shows me the error.

Comment: avoid square brackets, those are not a part of the C# unless you\re indexing something like an array or dictionary. plug in just a number.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov Thank you it has fixed the error but now everyone can add currency using bot to me just not to themselves. do I state "else if"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `[RequireOwner]` Attribute at the top of the command.

```
[RequireOwner]
[Command("give"), Alias("Give", "gift", "Gift"), Summary("Used to give or gift people golden coins")]
public async Task Give(IUser User = null, int Amount = 0)
{
    SocketGuildUser User1 = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
    //Give currency to the user.
}
```

The attribute will let the command service check for you if the person executing this command is the Bot's owner (you). It will ignore the command if it's not from the bot owner .

Comment: Works now!, Thank you so much!